# How to clear the filled form data of nested lists in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile application using jquery mobile and spring mvc. In my application I have nested lists, In this nested lists I have some forms. When I fill the form and press on Home or back button and again when I open the form, the filled data in the form are not cleared(form fields are contain the previous filled data).

How to clear the filled form data of nested lists in jquery mobile?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery mobile loads all the data into the same page, so clicking back or home doesn't reload the page; it just changes what is displayed.

You need to decide which events should trigger the form to be cleared and run something like this when that event occurs

```
$("#myForm").each(function(){this.reset();});
```